# Number Theory Proof Involving Primes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $S$ be the set of positive integers of the form $6k+1$ for some integer $k$.

Find an irreducible $p \in S$ such that $p|ab$ for some $a,b \in S$ but $p \nmid a$ and $p \nmid b$.

I know that if p is prime and $p|ab$, the $p|a$ or $p|b$.

Comment: I just edited the question @TobErnack

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: The title “a number theory proof involving primes” really narrows it down from the other elementary number theory proofs, are you sure you can’t think of a better title?

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Since $p$ being a "regular" prime means that $p|ab \implies p|a $ or $p|b$, your irreducible must not be a "regular" prime. Can you find a number of the form $6k+1$ that has no factors that are $1\bmod 6$, but isn't prime?

Comment: 25 and 49 are in the form $6k+1$ and don't have factors 1 mod 6, I believe.

Comment: @ivyblue You're right about $25$, but $49=7\cdot 7$. I think you're on the right track, though.

Comment: 55, 85, 91, 115, . .  is another

Comment: I really dont understand the hint

Comment: would 325 work for this problem because if a=25 and b=13 it fits all the conditions except it being a prime

Comment: @ivyblue You're going to want to choose an integer $p$ that satisfies these conditions (that $p$ is not prime, but it has no divisors that are $1\bmod 6$.) Now, can you find $a$ and $b$ such that $p|ab$ but $p\nmid a$ and $p\nmid b$ using the factorization of $p$ in the standard integers?

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't Euclid's Lemma state that if $p$ is a prime and $p\mid ab$ then $p\mid a$ or $p\mid b$ or both. That would mean the answers doesn't exists right? Maybe I'm missing something here...

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Your question would really be better as a comment, since it doesn't answer the problem. The key is that $p$ is not prime.

Comment: Within the integers, yes primality and irreducibility are the same exact thing, so yes answer doesn’t exist within Z. The first step would be to think about the problem in a different space. $S$ which has a different algebraic structure on it. (I think this is what you were missing? I would read definitions on [prime](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element) and [irreducible](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_element) and then without reading about the solution, just try and think of such numbers in the question until you find one.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint:* If $a$ and $b$ are of the form $6k-1$, then $ab \in S$. Pick $a$ and $b$ regular primes. Then $ab$ will be  an irreducible element of $S$.